# Hazelcast EntryListener, how to avoid race condition?

Tags: publish-subscribe, hazelcast, event-listener

I'm trying to develop a subscription service using Hazelcast. The subscription would listen for entries added to a specific Map that satisfy a predicate. This can be achieved fairly easily with an [EntryListener](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/hazelcast/core/EntryListener.html).

However the local cache of the Map is not empty when I add the `EntryListener` (and the Map constantly receives updates). If you add an `EntryListener` to a Map which contains entries the `EntryListener` is not fired for any preexisting entries in the Map.

I could call `map.values( <predicate> )` but it is always possible for an entry to be added just after iterating through the Map but before the `EntryListener` is added since the call to `map.values(...)` and the call to `map.addEntryListener(...)` are *not* atomic.

In an ideal solution the sequence of events would be:

1. Add `EntryListener` with predicate
2. Receive all entries in the cache that match that predicate
3. Then receive updates/removes/adds as the events occur (matching the initial predicate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is an enterprise feature, 
[continuous-query-cache](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#continuous-query-cache) seems what you want. Please see [pre-population](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/config/QueryCacheConfig.java#L336) part. Pre-population helps to fill your cache from underlying imap by getting a snapshot of it according to supplied predicate. You can also find some samples [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/enterprise/continuous-query-cache/src/main/java).

Comment: I think you might be right here. I don't have an enterprise licence, I wonder if one could achieve this result with entry processors and filters.